# block function in ios

Tags: scope, objective-c-blocks

hello everyone I am new to IOS developement and I am working of block functions.I am confused about their working.My question is can we print the block function's parameters to outside its block.
My code is like

```
[messageRenderingOperation start:^(NSString * plainTextBodyString, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"plain text:%@",plainTextBodyString);
      }];
NSLog(@"plain text body:%@",plainTextBodyString);
```

My output ids as follows:-

plain text:hello world
plain text body:(null)

why this value is null. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

declare one variable outside block

```
__block NSString *plainTextString;

[messageRenderingOperation start:^(NSString * plainTextBodyString, NSError * error) {
        //assign value
        plainTextString =plainTextBodyString;
        NSLog(@"plain text:%@",plainTextBodyString);
      }];

//now you can access variable
NSLog(@"plain text body:%@",plainTextString);
```

or,

```
 __block NSString *plainTextString; 
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [messageRenderingOperation start:^(NSString * plainTextBodyString, NSError * error) { 
     //assign value 
    plainTextString =plainTextBodyString; 
    NSLog(@"plain text:%@",plainTextBodyString); 
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); }]; 
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); 
//now you can access variable 
    NSLog(@"plain text body:%@",plainTextString);
```

Please refer this tutorial for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: I print block variable in NSLog i.e plainTextString not plainTextBodyString

Comment: ok I got it, The code in the block is run asynchronously. So the code after the block is run before the code in the block has had a chance to run (or certainly complete at least).
dispatch_sync is semantically equivalent to a traditional mutex lock.
so use
dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
    //access shared resource
});

Comment: can you show me some coding stuff.because it shows error while declaring dispatch_sync(queue,^{});

Comment: I had applied this code in my app.by this execution just stopped at this block. nothing is print further.